# Include document number in header on every page after first page Qweb

Tags: odoo-11, qweb

How to add page number on right side with the same level as a company name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="adjustment_document" inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">

        <t t-call="report.external_layout"></t>

        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

what are the best ways to do it

thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer

```
 <template id="page_external_layout_header" inherit_id="web.external_layout_standard">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']/div[@class='row']/div[@name='company_address']" position="after">
              <div class="col-xs-2 text-muted pull-right"> 
                   <span class="page"/>
              </div>   
            </xpath>     
        </template>
```

[image]